# Drop a column based on the existence of another column

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, drop

I'm actually trying to figure out how to drop a column based on the existence of another column. Here is my problem :

I start with this DataFrame. Each "X" column is associated with a "Y" column using a number. (X_1,Y_1 / X_2,Y_2 ...)

```
  Index X_1 X_2 Y_1  Y_2                
    1    4   0   A   NaN
    2    7   0   A   NaN
    3    6   0   B   NaN
    4    2   0   B   NaN
    5    8   0   A   NaN
```

I drop NaN values using `pd.dropna()`. The result I get is this DataFrame :

```
  Index X_1 X_2 Y_1             
    1    4   0   A   
    2    7   0   A
    3    6   0   B
    4    2   0   B
    5    8   0   A
```

The problem is that I want to delete the "X" column associated to the "Y" column that just got dropped. I would like to use a condition that basically says :

"If Y_2 is not in the DataFrame, drop the X_2 column"

I used a `for` loop combined to `if`, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas ?

Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Can there be other columns lets say `X_3, Y_3...` or `Z_1, Z_2..` etc?

Comment: Yes ! In reality, the names are : CHA_COEXPM1_COR  CHA_COFMAT1_COR and the number goes from 1 to 18

Comment: And then how many levels of drops are there? Based on just CHA3? Based on CHA3_COEXPM01?

Comment: It is only based on the number in COEXPM1 and COFMAT1. I juste edited my comment to make it more clear sorry Henry.

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Setup

```
>>> df

       CHA_COEXPM1_COR  CHA_COEXPM2_COR CHA_COFMAT1_COR  CHA_COFMAT2_COR
Index                                                                   
1                    4                0               A              NaN
2                    7                0               A              NaN
3                    6                0               B              NaN
4                    2                0               B              NaN
5                    8                0               A              NaN
```

#### Solution

- Identify the columns having `NaN` values in any row
- Group the identified columns using the numeric identifier and `transform` using `any`
- Filter the columns using the boolean mask created in the previous step

```
m = df.isna().any()
m = m.groupby(m.index.str.extract(r'(\d+)_')[0]).transform('any')
```

#### Result

```
>>> df.loc[:, ~m]

       CHA_COEXPM1_COR CHA_COFMAT1_COR
Index                                 
1                    4               A
2                    7               A
3                    6               B
4                    2               B
5                    8               A
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'm not really comfortable with the extract function. What does (r'(\d+)_') mean ?

Comment: @Tekz `r'(\d+)_'` is a regular expression pattern. So basically the pattern translates **to capture *one or more number of digits* that are followed by a single underscore.** The `extract` function is used to extract the occurrence of this regular expression pattern. For documentation on `extract` function you may [refer this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modified example to be closer to actual DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
    'X_V1_C': {0: 4, 1: 7, 2: 6, 3: 2, 4: 8},
    'X_V2_C': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
    'Y_V1_C': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'A'},
    'Y_V2_C': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan}
})
```

```
   Index  X_V1_C  X_V2_C Y_V1_C  Y_V2_C
0      1       4       0      A     NaN
1      2       7       0      A     NaN
2      3       6       0      B     NaN
3      4       2       0      B     NaN
4      5       8       0      A     NaN
```

1. [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on any columns to be "saved"
2. [`Extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the numbers from the columns and create a MultiIndex

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+)')[0],
                                        df.columns])

0          1      2      1      2  # Numbers Extracted From Columns
      X_V1_C X_V2_C Y_V1_C Y_V2_C
Index                            
1          4      0      A    NaN
2          7      0      A    NaN
3          6      0      B    NaN
4          2      0      B    NaN
5          8      0      A    NaN
```

3. Check where There are groups with all NaN columns with [`DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) on axis=0 (columns) then [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) relative to level=0 (the number that was extracted)

```
col_mask = ~df.isna().all(axis=0).any(level=0)

0
1     True  # Keep 1 Group
2    False  # Don't Keep 2 Group
dtype: bool
```

4.filter the DataFrame with the mask using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) then [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) on the added number level

```
df = df.loc[:, col_mask.index[col_mask]].droplevel(axis=1, level=0)

       X_V1_C Y_V1_C
Index               
1           4      A
2           7      A
3           6      B
4           2      B
5           8      A
```

---

All Together

```
df = df.set_index('Index')

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.str.extract(r'(\d+)')[0],
                                        df.columns])
col_mask = ~df.isna().all(axis=0).any(level=0)
df = df.loc[:, col_mask.index[col_mask]].droplevel(axis=1, level=0)
```

`df`:

```
       X_V1_C Y_V1_C
Index               
1           4      A
2           7      A
3           6      B
4           2      B
5           8      A
```

Answer (score 0):

1. drop nas

   df.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)
2. compute suffixes and columns with both suffixes

   suffixes = [i[2:] for i in df.columns]
   cols = [c for c in df.columns if suffixes.count(c[2:]) == 2]
3. filter columns

   df[cols]

full code:

```
df = df.set_index('Index').dropna(axis=1)
suffixes = [i[2:] for i in df2.columns]
df[[c for c in df2.columns if suffixes.count(c[2:]) == 2]]
```